# Cannot import @metaplex-foundation/js and run in nodejs

Tags: metaplex-js

I try to run the example: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js-examples/tree/main/getting-started-expressjs

I import the @metaplex-foundation/js into a javascript file. However the i find the error:

**Error: Cannot find module 'getting-started-expressjs/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/cjs/index.cjs'**

It seems like when building the library in the dist folder the cjs is not generated.

Anybody knows how to fix it?

I believe it only happens in the new version:
"@metaplex-foundation/js": "^0.17.7",
"@solana/web3.js": "^1.69.0",

Answer (score 1):

Someone reported the same problem for `@metaplex-foundation/js` version 0.17.7: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js/issues/422

You can use the older versions (0.17.6, 0.17.5)